# How to set a default location of a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, chat

in my web page there is a chat window. When the chat's log is filled out, the user uses scrollbar in order to navigate between messages. I want my chat frame to present always the last message that is located at the  bottom. How can I do this using CSS, JavaScript?

Thanks,
Tomer

Comment: is your chat text in an iframe or a div?

Comment: the chat frame is a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even thou is not a tag on your question here is a jQuery solution i use for my chat web app:

```
//Where chat_message_tray is the scrollable div in your chat
function chat_scroll(chat_messages_tray){
   var scroll_amount = $(chat_messages_tray).attr("scrollHeight") -  $(chat_messages_tray).height();

   $(chat_messages_tray).animate({ scrollTop: scroll_amount}, 500);
}
```

Comment: Yep it requires the JavaScript jQuery libray, if you don't use jQuery you can ask a JS guru translate this to plain JavaScript OR you should really start using jQuery

Comment: Ofcourse I use the latest jQuery version, but it's not working. How do I call this function? Do I need to call it like this: document.onload=chat_scroll("my_chat_frame"); between head tags?

Comment: nah, just call the plain function from any jQuery block code, for example chat_scroll("#messages_tray)

Comment: do you have a link to your Site?

Comment: No, it's on my localhost. If it's not so simple I can give up :)

Comment: Im sorry to say this, but you just been lazy. Is at simple as chat_scroll("#tray"); here is a live DEMO http://jsbin.com/afuzo3/8/

Comment: I just can't make it work. I don't know why... Maybe the sources here will help you to help me. http://jsbin.com/afuzo3/11/edit

Comment: @tomericco In the code you provided you did not had jQuery included at ALL and your #chat_log container was not scrollable either, i added jQuery lib and some CSS http://jsbin.com/afuzo3/12

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements (the good ones, anyway) support a method called `scrollIntoView()`. If you have a reference to the DOM element corresponding to the last chat entry (a `<div>` or whatever) you can use `scrollIntoView()` to tell the browser that its surrounding content should be scrolled in order to make the `<div>` visible.

Now, with some complicated (or not-so-complicated, maybe; perhaps just unlucky) page layouts, I've had to contend with Internet Explorer wanting to scroll the wrong thing, or just do something weird to the page. The nature of a thing like `scrollIntoView()` is such that you're letting the browser decide exactly how it wants to do that scrolling. Generally, with fairly simple content in a simple scrolling container (one with "overflow: auto" and a fixed height, basically), it does work however.

Comment: ok, but each one of the messages is in a div where its id is "message" (for keeping the same style with CSS), so how can I overcome this one?

Comment: First, you definitely should *not* re-use the same "id" value for each message; that's invalid markup and can cause all sorts of problems. Give each message a unique "id" if they need an "id" at all, and use a "class" value if you need to control all of them with CSS. To find the last message, you can use something like `getElementsByTagName()` from the container, and then look for elements with the appropriate string in the "className" attribute. The last one will be, well, the last one :-)

Comment: Although it's ugly, i'm not a pro, I just want to set my scrollbar always to the most bottom state... Any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I don't think there's any easier way. There are other APIs that could be used, but you'd still have to find your elements.  For many reasons other than this scrollbar thing, please don't duplicate "id" values on multiple elements - it's just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

http://radio.javaranch.com/pascarello/2005/12/14/1134573598403.html

3rd result from Google - 'div scrollbar bottom'